# Joining two unequal dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes of unequal length. The first dataframe(df1) has column A with unique values and corresponding to that are column B and column C in the same dataframe.
The second dataframe(df2) has column named column A having multiple repetitions of values of Column A of df1 and corresponding to that column D and column E.
I want to join df1 to df2 on column A,  in such a way that they form one dataframe and the column B and column C has values corresponding to that in df1.

```
Df1

  column A. Column B

A.                     ab
B.                      bc
C.                      fg

Df2
Column A   column D
A.                      1
B.                       2
C.                       3
B.                        4
A.                        5
A.                         6



Df1 + Df2

Column A column D column B
A.                  1.              ab
B.                  2.               bc
C.                   3.              fg
B.                   4.              bc
A.                   5.              ab 
A.                    6.              ab
```

How to do that ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) without parameter `on` if only common column in both DataFrame is joined column `Column A` with left join:

```
print (DF1)
  Column A Column B  Column C
0       A.       ab         1
1       B.       bc         9
2       C.       fg         7

print (DF2)
  Column A  column D  column E
0       A.         1         8
1       B.         2         9
2       C.         3         7
3       B.         4         3
4       A.         5         1
5       A.         6         0
```

---

```
df = DF2.merge(DF1,how='left')
print (df)
  Column A  column D  column E Column B  Column C
0       A.         1         8       ab         1
1       B.         2         9       bc         9
2       C.         3         7       fg         7
3       B.         4         3       bc         9
4       A.         5         1       ab         1
5       A.         6         0       ab         1
```

If multiple same columns add `on`:

```
df = DF2.merge(DF1,how='left', on='Column A')
print (df)
  Column A  column D  column E Column B  Column C
0       A.         1         8       ab         1
1       B.         2         9       bc         9
2       C.         3         7       fg         7
3       B.         4         3       bc         9
4       A.         5         1       ab         1
5       A.         6         0       ab         1
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `'Column A'` is the only column in common, `merge` uses all common columns by default.

```
DF2.merge(DF1, 'left')

  Column A  column D  column E Column B  Column C
0       A.         1         8       ab         1
1       B.         2         9       bc         9
2       C.         3         7       fg         7
3       B.         4         3       bc         9
4       A.         5         1       ab         1
5       A.         6         0       ab         1
```

---

`join` uses the index, so we set the index of the `DF1` and `join` it to `DF2`.  By default, it would require we set the index of `DF2` as well, but we specify the `on='Column A'` parameter so that we can keep `'Column A'` in the dataframe proper.

```
DF2.join(DF1.set_index('Column A'), on='Column A')

  Column A  column D  column E Column B  Column C
0       A.         1         8       ab         1
1       B.         2         9       bc         9
2       C.         3         7       fg         7
3       B.         4         3       bc         9
4       A.         5         1       ab         1
5       A.         6         0       ab         1
```

Comment: @jezrael.  And this is why the pandas tag is magic.  Almost any reasonably constructed question will be competently covered....  And pretty quickly.